# How to extract specific data from a string that shows up multiple times

Tags: python

I have a program that can give me all the coordinates within a specified distance from a given point and it gives me the coordinates like this:
Point(52.02845474684852, 177.1785836798103, 0.0)
I am wondering how to take the first two numbers (52.02845474684852 and 177.1785836798103) and make each number a variable. It is important to note that 0.0 may show up in the first two numbers eventually and therefore can't just be removed normally.

Example:

```
distance_data = open("Distance from start.txt", "w")
for i range (len(distance_data))
    point = distance_data[i+1]
    #point = Point(52.02845474684852, 177.1785836798103, 0.0)  
    #Something happens here that extracts the numbers and makes them their own variables.
```

Comment: What data type is a `Point()` ? Likely you can either access it as `Point[0]`, `Point['x']` or `Point.x`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to find all integers or floating point numbers, and return a list. You can then just pick the first 2:

```
import re

p = "Point(1.456, -7, 32, 16.8345, 14)"
result = re.findall(r'[+-]?(?:\d+[.])?\d+', p)
print(result[0:2])
# [1.456, -7]
```

You will however need a more complicated pattern if your numbers include negative numbers,

Comment: It works fine when I use that directly but when I put it in a for loop and change out p to p=distance_data_to_add[i] the line that gives result gives this error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: My updated code is this:                                                                                               
for i in range (len(distance_data_to_add)):
    p = distance_data_to_add[i]
    result = re.findall(r'[+-]?(?:\d+[.])?\d+', p)
    print(result[0:2])

Comment: That implies that `p` isn't a string - you should print out `p` before the `findall` and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It gives a geopy.point.Point and can be accessed using a special function. It can be found in the documentation on page 68, Chapter 4. Data

Comment: Good! Could you include a relevant portion of the documentation in your answer, like how to call the function ? So that others who have the same problem can see it.